# Make DNS Record entries using WMI from powershell

Tags: powershell, wmi

Disclaimer: I am very new to powershell and almost ignorant of WMI.

I am trying to make dns entries on a remote server through powershell. I have googled and found WMI to be the only way.

So the following code snippet works for me

```
$dnsAType = [wmiclass]"\\$dnsServer\root\MicrosoftDNS:MicrosoftDNS_AType"
    $dnsAType.CreateInstanceFromPropertyData($dnsServer, $dnsZone, $domainName, $class, $ttl, $ipaddress)
```

The problem is that I have to make these entries as a different user. The user that I am logged in as does not have enough privileges. So I have to pass in credentials. Get-WmiObject seems to be the only way of passing in different credentials. But I am not able to get the code working for Get-WmiObject .

The following snippet works gets me the wmi_objects.

```
$wmi_object = Get-WmiObject -Class MicrosoftDNS_AType -Namespace "root\MicrosoftDNS" -computerName "192.168.1.5" -Credential $creds
```

But that seems to be an array and the elements do not seem to have the CreateInstanceFromPropertyData method that I was expecting. I am kind of confused as to how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Googling for this only gives me results for using wmi literals(I guess that is what they are?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We got this to work the following way:

We enabled PowerShell Remoting on both local and remote machines and got it working through Invoke-Command

```
    PS>Enable-PSRemoting
    PS>Invoke-Command {
    $dnsAType = [wmiclass]"root\MicrosoftDNS:MicrosoftDNS_AType"
        $dnsAType.CreateInstanceFromPropertyData($dnsServer, $dnsZone, $domainName, $class, $ttl, $ipaddress)
    } -Credentials $cred -ComputerName $remotemachineName
```

There is only one thing that you have to be running with elevated permissions.  Hope this helps others.

Comment: Well Remote executing WMI which is a network protocol works, but on my point of view it's not so nice.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PowerShell V2, you can use `Set-WMIInstance` for that.

```
Set-WMIInstance -Namespace "root\MicrosoftDNS" -class MicrosoftDNS_AType -argument @{DnsServerName="srventr2.societe.fr"; ContainerName="societe.fr" ; OwnerName="t1.societe.fr"; RecordData="192.168.10.10" ; RecordClass=1 ; TTL=3600 } -credential (get-credential) -computername "192.168.183.138"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me sorry. Although I am running powershellV2. I get this error

`Set-WmiInstance : Generic failure
At line:1 char:16
+ Set-WMIInstance <<<<  -Namespace "root\MicrosoftDNS" -class MicrosoftDNS_AType -argument @{DnsServerName="192.168.1.10
"; ContainerName="Foo.Bar.local" ; RecordData="192.168.1.20" ; RecordClass=1 ; TTL=3600 } -credential $creds -computer "
192.168.1.10"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Set-WmiInstance], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SetWMIManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetWmiInstance`

Comment: You forgot `OwnerName` parameter

Answer (score 1):

Check the properties of $dnsAType.psbase.Scope.Options, you can set username and password along with some other connection options:

```
PS > $dnsAType.psbase.Scope.Options    

Locale           :
Username         :
Password         :
SecurePassword   :
Authority        :
Impersonation    : Impersonate
Authentication   : Unchanged
EnablePrivileges : False
Context          : {}
Timeout          : 10675199.02:48:05.4775807
```

Comment: Not sure if this will work as I can't get an instance of $dnsAType unless I didn't understand what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share knowledge:

If you want to do that on local server (server.contoso.com) and you have at least one instance of SRV record

```
PS C:\> $record = Get-WmiObject -namespace "root\MicrosoftDNS" -class MicrosoftDNS_SRVType
PS C:\> $record[0].CreateInstanceFromTextRepresentation("server.contoso.com", "contoso.com", "_mysvc._tcp.contoso.com IN SRV 0 100 8000 host1.contoso.com")
```

Answer (score -1):

Still relevant today...

As for alternate credentials, in previous answers: -Credential

However, Powershell can be a bit "hokey" when it comes to returning the correct Interface.

The following command will return MicrosoftDNS_ResourceRecord (even though we asked for MicrosoftDNS_AType)

```
GWMI -Class MicrosoftDNS_AType -ComputerName $dns `
     -Namespace root\MicrosoftDNS -Credential username | GM
```

As an alternative the following command will return MicrosoftDNS_AType

```
GWMI -Class MicrosoftDNS_AType -ComputerName $dns `
     -Namespace root\MicrosoftDNS -Credential username -List | GM
```

To accomplish your task:

```
(GWMI -Class MicrosoftDNS_AType -ComputerName $dns `
      -Namespace root\MicrosoftDNS -Credential username `
      -List).CreateInstanceFromPropertyData($dnsFqdn,$zone, $host, 1, 3600, $ip)
```